# Login through REST API in Django

Tags: python, django, rest, post

I have a Django REST API server for my project. It uses built-in login system on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-auth/login/`. 
I have additional Django project, that interacts with REST server and manages info from it. To view data, firstly I need to log in.
So I created a form in `forms.py`:

```
   class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='username', max_length=50)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

And html template:

```
<form action="{% url 'todolist:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And appropriate view in `views.py`:

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post_data = {'username': form.cleaned_data['username'], 'password': form.cleaned_data['password']}
            response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-auth/login/', data=post_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/todolists/')
```

But I get 403 Forbidden. What is a proper way to manage authorization?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue ? I was wondering if this part of your project is accessible for reading purposes ?

Answer (score 0):

django.middleware.csrf.get_token() is used for to get token internally, please add header with csrf token in python code and refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/

Comment: I can log in accessing my REST API server url. I try to login not though built-in REST login form, but through my Django app that is a connector between REST API server and client.

Comment: you mean want to login rest api through another django app right?

Answer (score 0):

In Views.py ,csrf_token is missing,so change your code like this,

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post_data = {'username':  form.cleaned_data['username'],'password': form.cleaned_data['password']}
            response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-auth/login/', data=post_data)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/todolists/')
```

If you are django version above 1.7, **`@method_decorator` should be used in django-api view.**

Another way of doing ,is You can perform request to api with userdetails(username and password) as data in ajax using jquery and pass csrf-token value in header as csrf token can be get using

```
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
```

and in ajax success call you will get the response and redirect to new page as you mentioned in Views.py.It will load the content without refreshing page.

Hope it may helps!

Comment: Going first way, I tried to write decorator before class statement, but django fails. Writing decorators before each class method worked out, but it doesn't  solve my problem. Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api-auth/login/
[10/May/2017 14:47:19] "POST /api-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2857

Comment: You need to add csrf_exempt decorator for this ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api-auth/login/) api's view.